# Error Offlajn extensions

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, mysql, error-handling

The contact page of my site ( [url]https://www.portal-gestao.com/contactos.html[/url]) is returning the error:

```
Table 'portalge_2015.j30_offlajn_forms' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT fields FROM j30_offlajn_forms WHERE state=1 AND type='registration' AND (id < 99 OR language='pt-PT') ORDER BY id
```

This is just supposed to display the core Joomla contact form.

The same error is displayed when trying to edit a user in the backend.

I don't have any extension from offlajn installed anymore (I had improved ajax login & register in the past but had lots of bugs), so this is really something crazy.

Is it possible that some core joomla files have been hacked?

I tried extracting J3.4 files over again but the error persists.

Any help anyone?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

If you have any problem with the purchased extensions from Offlajn, you can create a support ticket on our site:

http://offlajn.com/contact-us.html

Our kind support team is always ready to help you.

In your case you have uninstalled all of the parts of the Improved AJAX Login & Register, except the System - Improved AJAX Login and Register system plugin, which was still active. So that's why you got that message refers to a database table, which was not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`offlajn_forms` is not a core Joomla table. It belongs to an **offlajn** extension, so there is something on your site trying to pull data from this table.

You say that it is no longer installed, however please check for plugins, modules, components and libraries.

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Extensions** >> **Extension Manager** >> **Manage**

Then in the search box, type in something like the first 3 letter of the extension (`off`) and uninstall any results that are associated with it.